# randomly increment through an array, c++

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, srand

I am struggling to understand the concept of randomly reading numbers from an array of integers using 'rand()'. I have created a random number generator between 1-3 and want to output an index of an array, then for the generator to randomly output the next generated number from the previous index, until it reaches the end of the array. For example:

1. 'rand()'= 3, 'array[2]'
2. 'rand()' = 2, 'array[4]'
3. 'rand()' = 3, 'array[7]'

if that makes sense?? etc, etc.

The code I'm currently using just outputs a sequence of random numbers. I have place a 'seed' so I can look at the same sequence.

```
int main() 
{ 
 int arrayTest[20] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
 17, 18, 19, 20};   
 srand(4);
 for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)  
    {  
     arrayTest[i] = (rand() % 3);
     cout << arrayTest[i] << endl;
    }




}
```

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is that you're trying to iterate over an array in random increments, instead of one element at a time. But this is so confusingly worded that it's completely unclear. Please make your question more clear. Even the shown example, of allegedly generating random numbers 1-3, somehow ends up producing the values 5 and 6.

Comment: You are using srand with a constant number, which will make the output the same all the time. You should use another source of randomness, such as the time. Also, you should use C++11's random number generators [Link here](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: @mamg22 read the question again. If one thing it is clear, it is that seed is designed to be the same for repetitive results.

Comment: @SergeyA Oh, i didn't see that

Comment: @mamg22 yes please read what I put first. The Problem has been solved anyhow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am somewhat guessing at what you really want. But it seems to want to make random increments to an index, and use that index to read from the array in  a loop.

So this code just doesn't do anything like you want

```
 arrayTest[i] = (rand() % 3);
```

It writes (not reads) a random value to an array using a sequential (i.e. non-random) index.

Here's what I *think* you want

```
int main() 
{ 
    int arrayTest[20] = { ... };   
    srand(4);
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)  
    {  
         index += (rand() % 3) + 1; // add random number from 1 to 3 to index
         if (index >= 20) // if index too big for array
             index -= 20; // wrap around to beginning of array
         cout << arrayTest[index] << endl; // read array at random index, and output
    }
}
```

But I'm not completely sure, in particular the way your `testArray` has the numbers 1 to 20 in order is making me a bit suspicious. Maybe if you explain why you want to do whatever you want to do it would be a bit clearer.

Comment: firstly, apologies for my poor english. Picture the 'rand()' as a die, say if the first number to generate is 3 - this means it lands on testArray[2]. The second number to generate is 2 - this means it lands on testArray[4], and so on and so on until the for loop has reached the end. Apologies again.

Comment: @C.Mann OK well that sounds a lot like what I wrote above. Give it a try.

Comment: Yes the numbers that were ordered from 1-20 in the array are there for a purpose. E.g. If first number to generate is 3, then it lands to output testArray[2] //output is = {3}, The second number to generate is 2 - lands on testArray[4] //output is = {5}

Comment: @C.Mann So you don't need the array then. `arrayTest[i] == i + 1` always, so `cout << arrayTest[index] << endl;` is exactly the same as `cout << index + 1 << endl;`. So you can get rid of the array, I think maybe it was confusing you in any case.

Comment: This is still incorrect as I need to get to the elements of the array. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @C.Mann Can you run john's code & explain how's its output is different from what you expect? At the moment it appears to do what you've asked for, i.e. Increment the array's index by the random result & output that number.

Comment: @ItsPete I want it so it increments through the Arrays index and outputs the current value in that index e.g. If first number to generate is 3, then it lands to output testArray[2] //output is = {3}, The second number to generate is 2 - lands on testArray[4] //output is = {5}, The third number to generate is 2 - lands on testArray[6] //output is = {7}, The fourth number to generate is 3 - lands on testArray[9] //output is = {10}, and so on until it reaches the end of the array. I'm going to learn how to use iterators as that might be best suited for what I want.

Comment: @ItsPete at the moment on John's code it outputs "2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3" etc etc

Comment: @john SOLVED: I changed the array to vector, I then created an iterator and written my code as: (it = vectorTest.begin(); it != vectorTest.end(); it = it + rand() %3) {cout << *it << endl;} ... Thanks for your help you definitely guided me in the right direction.

Comment: @C.Mann Glad it help and it sounds like you ended up with good code. My code above had an error I wrote `index = (rand() % 3) + 1;` when I meant `index += (rand() % 3) + 1;`. With that change my code would have done something like what you expected. Serves me right for not testing what I wrote.

Comment: @john just tested that too, works fine. Appreciate the help, will be more clear with my questions in future